# Random ErrorInvalidPropertyRequest on Outlook Contacts requests

Tags: office365, outlook.com, office365-apps

I'm making proper `GET` calls to:

`https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Me/Contacts?$orderby=DisplayName`

Unfortunately about one in every 15 calls fails with the following exception.

Any ideas what's wrong?

```
"{\"error\":{\"code\":\"ErrorInvalidPropertyRequest\",\"message\":\"Property is not valid for this object type.\",\"innererror\":{\"message\":\"\\\"Exchange service returned error ErrorInvalidPropertyRequest: Property is not valid for this object type.\\\".\",\"type\":\"Microsoft.Exchange.Services.ExchangeService.ExchangeServiceErrorResponseException\",\"stacktrace\":\"   at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.ExchangeService.ExchangeServiceHelper.CheckResponse(IExchangeWebMethodResponse response, ExecutionOption option)\\r\\n   at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.ExchangeService.ExchangeServiceBase.InvokeServiceCommand[TResponse](Func`1 commandCreator, ExecutionOption executionOption)\\r\\n   at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.ContactProvider.InternalRead(String ewsId, ContactQueryAdapter queryAdapter)\\r\\n   at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.ContactProvider.Find(String parentFolderId, ContactQueryAdapter queryAdapter)\\r\\n   at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.FindContactsCommand.InternalExecute()\\r\\n   at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.ODataCommand`2.Execute()\\r\\n   at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.ODataTask.Execute(TimeSpan queueAndDelayTime, TimeSpan totalTime)\"}}}"
```